# How is the total range of a weapon calculated when the Distance property and Improved Far Shot are involved?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ranged-attack

The [Distance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/distance) magic weapon ability doubles the range increment of a ranged weapon and the [Improved Far Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/rite-publishing/general-feats---3rd-party---rite-publishing/improved-far-shot) feat increases the range increment of ranged and thrown weapons the character wields by 50%.

Let's take a longbow for the sake of simplicity : its base range increment is 100 feet.

When a character with the Improved Far Shot feat wields a +1 distance longbow, is the range increment 250 feet (100+100+50) or 300 feet (100*2*1.5) ?

Answer (score 5):

In general, if you are not dealing with dice, then normal math rules apply.

Distance gives you a multiplier of x2.

IFS gives you a multiplier of x1.5.

100 x2 x1.5 = 300

100 x1.5 x2 = 300

As explained in the examples in IFS, you take the weapons distance and multiply by 1.5. Your distance longbow has a range of 200ft. It doesn't matter that it only has that range because of distance, or its a custom item, or whatever, IFS just takes what you give it and return 1.5 times that amount.